# How can I send the dryRun parameter to pandas.read_gbq function

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I would like to get an estimate of the query size from bigquery before running it to load into pandas dataframe.
How can I use the [dryRun](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun) parameter with the [read_gbq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html) function?

Comment: What happens if you pass `{'dryRun': True}` for the `**kwargs`?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard
When running

`df = gbq.read_gbq(query, private_key=cred, project_id=project, dialect='standard', kwargs={'dryRun': True})`

df has data.

Comment: what about `gbq.read_gbq(query, private_key=cred, project_id=project, dialect='standard', 'dryRun': True)`

Comment: @FelipeHoffa
Assuming you meant dryRun=True
I still get the data back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you won't be able to do so indeed.

If you check how the pandas [BigQuery Connector](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L558) works, you'll see that it only updates the `query` settings for the job.

`dryRun` is outside the query definition and on the same level actually.

I'm not sure why this works the way it does (maybe the creators of pandas-gbq didn't want pandas to be a direct replacement for all types of jobs you can run in BQ). Still, I've started this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/88) on their repository, you can follow it to see their input on this one.

As a possible workaround, I'd recommend using the official python API for interacting with GCP in general, specifically, you could use the BigQuery Client. Installing it should be quite easy:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

And then you could run:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/your/key.json'

query = """your query"""
bc = Client()

job = client.run_sync_query(query)
job.use_legacy_sql = False
job.dryRun = True

job.run()

print(job.total_bytes_processed)
```

Comment: Thanks @willian-fuks!